# How to fix loop that won't work twice with the same input

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to make a simple program that asks for an integer and if that integer is a prime number, outputs its factors. If the user's input is not a prime factor, it asks for the user to enter a prime factor. The problem is if I enter a valid prime factor twice in a row, it doesn't give me the correct output. I have been working at this for a while now and I think it must be something obvious that I am missing because I cannot figure it out.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> factors = new List<int>();
        int a, b, c;
        Console.Write("Hello,\n Please enter an integer: ");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        while (userInput != "quit")
        {
            try
            {
                a = int.Parse(userInput);
                c = a;
                bool negative = a < 0;
                int letter = Convert.ToInt32(Int32.TryParse(userInput, out letter));
                if (!negative && letter != 0)
                {
                    for (b = 2; a > 1;)
                        if (a % b == 0)
                        {                
                            while (c % b == 0)
                            {
                                c /= b;
                                factors.Add(c);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine($"{a} has factors: { String.Join(", ", factors)}");
                            Console.Write("Please enter another integer: ");
                            factors.Clear();
                            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                            a = int.Parse(userInput);


                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Please enter a valid prime factor: ");
                    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter a valid prime factor: ");
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hello,
 Please enter an integer: 64...
64 has factors: 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
Please enter another integer: y...
Please enter a valid prime factor:

now if I do two valid prime factors in a row

Hello,
 Please enter an integer: 64...
64 has factors: 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
Please enter another integer: 8...
8 has factors:
Please enter another integer:

however....

Hello,
 Please enter an integer: 64...
64 has factors: 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
Please enter another integer: y...
Please enter a valid prime factor: 8
8 has factors: 4, 2, 1
Please enter another integer:

Comment: Please refactor your code so you can show problem without user input and then [edit] post with true [MCVE] with all data shown inline in the code.

Comment: Side note: using good long variable names is much better than "a", "b", "c" (which is only marginally better than x342, x564, x234) as  you would know how that value is used in the code and if it makes sense to change in particular piece of code.

Comment: The for loop does not have a block. Also you need to Share the sample input and expected output . Did you debug the code?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I added examples of input and output showing what works and what doesn't. I don't think I can reduce the code anymore than what it is already. Thank you for the advice on the naming

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I added examples of input/output at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Normally i wouldnt just provide the answer because it is important for a developer to be able to solve these issues by themselves. But I am unable to respond in the comments. So i will provide some feedback that led me to the solution and some general comments.

If you spend time debugging you will be able to see the issues in the code. Adding simple Console.WriteLines to indicate where in the code flow things start to go wrong.

You also need to provide better names for variables. a, b, c are meaningless and are hard to understand the purpose of. Better variable names mean we can better understand the problem you are having but also what the code is trying to do. A well written block of code should be readable and generally understandable within 5 seconds. I did my best to apply it your code generally, without restructing too much so you can see the points of redundancy in the code in comparison.

The issue was when i debugged your code was what seemed like an infinite loop occurring or some oddity with the int parsing. Because i didnt want to spend too much time understanding why that was happening, I made the above suggestions to the code to see if just by reducing code complexity and improving readability that I could reduce the risk of the bug occurring.

The below solution may not be 100% in line with what you are after, it is hard to know that based on lack of expected results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> factors = new List<int>();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer: ");
            var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userInput.Equals("quit"))
                break;

            if (!Int32.TryParse(userInput, out var firstOut)
               || !Int32.TryParse(userInput, out var secondOut))
                continue; 

            if (firstOut % 2 != 0 || firstOut < 0)
                continue;

            while (secondOut % 2 == 0)
            {
                secondOut /= 2;
                factors.Add(secondOut);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{firstOut} has factors: {String.Join(", ", factors)}");
            factors.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @lachlan.p.jordan this fixed one of the problems I was trying to address, however, set me back on the problem of dealing with invalid entries from the user such as negative numbers or non-numerical characters. Unfortunately, I am not really sure how your code fixed it but never-the-less it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: hey @Paul take a look at the updated code now. it provides the additional checks that i removed